# Can't use keyboard "AT Keyboard not present"

Tags: terminal, keyboard

I am working on an embedded system, and during the boot sequence, two lines show up saying:

keyboard: Timeout - AT keyboard not present?(ed)

keyboard: Timeout - AT keyboard not present?(f4)

I know the keyboard works, as I can get into the BIOS and change settings at whatnot, but I am unable to use the keyboard in the system.
The embedded system I am working on unfortunately does not have PS/2 connections, only usb. I have tried to use a PS/2 to usb addapter, but that didn't do anything

Comment: What setup is this? Exact machine, peripherals, ...? How do you know that the keyboard works?

Comment: Xe knows that the keyboard works because xe "can get into the BIOS [SETUP] and change settings and whatnot".  The hidden question, buried under the AT keyboard wild goose chase, is _Why does my USB keyboard work in the firmware SETUP program but not once my Linux-based operating system has bootstrapped, and how do I fix it?_  Of course, there's not enough information here to answer that.

Comment: If the embedded system has no PS/2 connections and a PS/2 to USB adapter doesn't work, I don't understand how you connected the keyboard in order for the BIOS to see it. Please edit question to clarify. (P.S. new shiny USB keyboards can be bought for the price of two cups of coffee, why clinging to PS/2?)

Comment: From experience, RedGrittyBrick, one can take an educated guess at the questioner's reasoning. _My USB keyboard does not work.  Hmmm.  I see this error message complaining that there's no AT keyboard.  Perhaps Linux requires an AT keyboard to be present.  It seems to be saying that.  Alright, let's try this spare AT keyboard that I've dug up.  Where to plug it in?  Oh.  Alright, I'll use an PS/2-to-USB adapter and plug it in there.  That should satisfy Linux, surely?_

Comment: The system i'm running is a GENE-BT05 [link](https://www.aaeon.com/en/p/3-and-half-inches-subcompact-boards-gene-bt05). BTW, the distro is Coyote Linux

Comment: @808.exe I have just read all the comments from others wondering about what your problem is. Then you return and say something tangential to the conversation. I would really like some clarity. So read the comments, then edit the question to make it clearer. Oh I have just realised that I have written a comment to ask you to read the comments (I will vote you down, that may get your attention: I will remove down-vote and consider up-vote after the edit).

Answer (score 2):

I think you issue is in BIOS not the OS. Linux should detect a USB keyboard w/o problems if the BIOS is correct.

Try to find something in bios similar to:

"legacy usb support"

and set it to legacy. 
OR
Depending on your BIOS you may find something like this:

USB Keyboard support via BIOS (in place of OS)

Dig around in BIOS and see what the USB settings will do for you.

Comment: Hi mark. I have checked the bios fully for any settings related to USB. I have legacy USB support enabled and it shows under usb devices "1 keyboard, 1 mouse, 2 hubs". Funny enough I don't have a mouse plugged in but I don't think this is a big deal. In the south bridge settings, under USB configuration, I have xHCI mode set to auto, and all but one option say they are enabled. The one that says disabled is USB 2.0(EHCI) Support

Comment: One thing to try, If you have high speed usb3 (blue) and low speed (black) usb ports plug the keyboard into the black. (or swap to blue if already in black) and try to reboot.